# Shell equivalent to PHP's preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, bash, preg-replace, unix

Greetz folks.

I'm looking for a way to do the same stuff than PHP's [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) does (search text matching a regular expression and replace it) in a shell script.

So, consider the following file.

```
<a href="http://example.com/">Website #1</a>
<a href="http://example.net/">Website #2</a>
<a href="http://example.org/">Website #3</a>
```

And I want to get this:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.net/
http://example.org/
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Your text differs from your example. Do you want to extract part(s) of your strings (as in your examples) or do you want to actually replace it with something?

Comment: Also, [don't parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (in general).

Comment: If you say, "So, consider the following file.", then people are gonna assume it's the data. Make a proper question next time.

Comment: @plundra Yes, sorry. Actually you're right, "extract" is the correct word. @delnan Well I just want to extract some strings... @Anders You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `sed` as:

```
sed -r 's/.*href="([^"]*)".*/\1/' file
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/yFmhb)

Comment: Great, thanks! So I assume `s` is to tell sed to use a regex but what is `\1/` for?

Comment: No, `s` is substitute and `\1` is the first match (group? unsure about the term), 1 being the content of the first parenthesis. `[^"]*` in the case above.

Answer (score 0):

While `sed` is perfectly suitable, it doesn't allow more than 9 backreferences. Perl does:

```
echo "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z" | \
    perl -lpe 's/(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)/$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;$9;$10;$11;$12;$13;$14;$15;$16;$17;$18;$19;$20;$21;$22;$23;$24;$25;$26/g'
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;y;z
```

This (dumb) example show it's possible to go further than `sed`'s `\9`